# Antimer L3+ - Approximately How Many Coins In 30 days

Tags: litecoin, antminer

I am about to receive one L3+ LiteCoin miner with
A hash speed of 4TH/s.

Approximately, how much litecoin could I 
reasonably expect to mine in 30 days with my L3+
running at full operating speed 24/7, with unlimited 
bandwidth up/down for my internet connection to
the miner? Approximately??

Thanks in advance for any response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Antimer L3+ could be making about 32 USD per Antminer per day. But the total over 30 days depends on a lot of things. If you take an average of 30$ over 30 days and bitcoin price average of 11,000, then you could make 900$.

Also, you need to include other things like a power outage, internet connection down, and hardware issues to be on safer side.

Let us know if this answers your question.

Comment: If mining litecoin; currently around $1100 per coin, would this influence the $900 value in 30 days you mentioned above?

Comment: According to the link I am using, you could get 97$ a day. But check the parameters are correct for calculation at https://www.coinwarz.com/calculators/litecoin-mining-calculator/?h=4000000.00&p=1000.00&pc=0.10&pf=0.00&d=3731199.18337428&r=25.00000000&er=0.01603501&btcer=11569.00000000&hc=0.00

Comment: Thanks for the info and the link to the calculator! Much appreciated.